# Find a match followed by another match in a different line and sort the output

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep, xargs

I have a file that is in the following format:

```
First Name : aa
#some noninteresting info
...
#some noninteresting info
Last Name : tt
First Name : cc
#some noninteresting info
...
#some noninteresting info
Last Name : ss
```

I need to produce another file which only has first and last names and is sorted based on last name:

```
First Name : cc
Last Name : ss
First Name : aa
Last Name : tt
```

I tried the following:

```
grep "Last Name :" | sort
```

But this is only half of what I want. How can I add First Name to this which corresponds to the last name and keep them sorted based on the last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU `sed` then you can pipe the output of `grep` to it.

```
grep -E '(First|Last) Name' file | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | sort -k8 | sed 's/Last/\nLast/'
First Name : cc
Last Name : ss
First Name : aa
Last Name : tt
```

- `grep -E '(First|Last) Name' file` will grep the lines with First and Last Names
- `sed 'N;s/\n/ /'` will add the append the Last Name to First Name
- `sort -k8` will sort the 8th field which is Last Name value
- `sed 's/Last/\nLast/'` will place them on separate lines

If you don't have GNU `sed` then your other option would be to use `xargs`:

```
grep -E '(First|Last) Name' file | xargs -n8 | sort -k8 | xargs -n4
First Name : cc
Last Name : ss
First Name : aa
Last Name : tt
```

**Note:** This assumes that your data has First Name and Last Names for every entries. `xargs` solution assumes that your First Name has no Middle Name

Comment: How should I change sed to connect three lines if I had three fields (for example First, Last, Age)?

Comment: @Ari For including `Age` you could do `grep -E '(First|Last|Age)' file | sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g' | sort -k8 | sed 's/Last\|Age/\n&/g'`

Comment: @jaypal Nice work.  However, given the propensity of people using obvious fake data such as `Last` for a last name, I'd be a little wary of that joining and splitting method for the lines using `sed`.  At the very least, I'd suggest adding a random delimiter like `~` to help prevent adding extraneous returns when splitting the lines back.

Comment: @Miller I think `First Name :` and `Last Name :` are fixed parameters with values next to them (eg. `cc`, `ss`, `aa`, `tt`). Having said that I do agree with your comment. The first `sed` just appends consecutive line and second one splits based on parameter name which OP used in his question.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use regular expressions to accomplish the filtering:

```
grep -E "(Last|First) Name :"
```

But to have them "in order" of last name while displaying the first name, you'll need to do more processing before you sort. Perhaps you can look at `sed` and `awk` to help with that part.

A way you can do this is by changing the regular expressions to have a single match encompass both first and last name's lines, append the last name to the beginning of the match, sort it, and remove the last name.... complex, but a doable method.

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -e 'print sort {@l = map /([^:]*)\Z/, $a, $b; $l[0] cmp $l[1]} split /(?=^First)/m, join q{}, grep /Name :/, <>' file.txt
```

Breaking it down.  Read bottom to top.

```
perl -e '
     print                                                   # Print results
     sort {@l = map /([^:]*)\Z/, $a, $b; $l[0] cmp $l[1]}    # Sort based off last phrase after a :
     split /(?=^First)/m,                                    # Split on lines beginning with First
     join q{},                                               # Join all lines together
     grep /Name :/,                                          # Filter all those not containing Name :
     <>                                                      # Slurp all the lines
   ' file.txt
```